# Symfony 4 routes not using method param

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Looking through the [current docs for routing](https://symfony.com/doc/master/routing/requirements.html#adding-http-method-requirements) for Symfony 4 I see that I should be able to use annotations to route based on endpoint and HTTP method (GET, POST, etc.).

But, with the following controller, a browser pointed to the "/" endpoint returns "Hello" regardless of whether it's sending a GET request or a POST request.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ArticleController {
    /**
     * @Route:("/", methods={"POST"});
     */
    public function post() {
        return new Response('<html><body>Hello</body></html>');
    }

    /**
     * @Route:("/", methods={"GET"});
     */
    public function get() {
        return new Response('<html><body>Hey</body></html>');
    }
}
```

Bug? Or pilot error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pilot error :) It's:

```
* @Route("/", methods={"GET"});
```

Note the errant semicolon just after `@Route` in your original definition.

Comment: That's crazy. How'd those get in there? I certainly didn't put them there ;)

Comment: Me neither! It happens I guess—code gremlins :)